# Ada 95 Check if enter was pressed

Tags: ada

I am new to Ada.

How can I check if enter was pressed?

The while loop should be able to check whether the input character is a white space or an enter key.

Furthermore, how can I check the user input type, like the `type()` or `typeof()` function in other languages?

```
FUNCTION ReadValue RETURN Unbounded_String IS
      ValueChar : Character;
      Result : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String("NULL");
   BEGIN
      Get(ValueChar);
      Skip_Line;

      WHILE ValueChar /= ';'LOOP
         Get(ValueChar);
         IF IsValidNameInput(ValueChar) THEN 
            Result := Result & ValueChar;
         ELSE
            exit;
         END IF;         
      END LOOP;
      ValueIntegerFlag  := CheckValue(Value);

      RETURN Result;

   END ReadValue;
```

Comment: Do you really mean Ada 95? things have moved on since then.

Comment: @SimonWright yes it is ada 95 lol.

Comment: I think you should take the `CheckValue` call outside `ReadValue`. I did this in my answer without remarking on it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the characters one-at-a-time without special ENTER handling using `Get_Immediate` instead of `Get` - [ARM A.10.7(9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-7.html#p9).

You can do checks on the class of the character you’ve just read using `Ada.Characters.Handling` - [ARM A.3.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-3-2.html) - something like

```
function Is_Valid_Name_Input (Ch : Character) return Boolean is
begin
   return Ada.Characters.Handling.Is_Graphic (Ch)
     and then not Ada.Characters.Handling.Is_Space (Ch);
end Is_Valid_Name_Input;
```

(probably not quite what you want, since it makes `&*^$$^` a valid name!)

`Ada.Characters.Handling.Is_Line_Terminator` detects ENTER (on Unix; probably on Windows too).

You can check whether a string corresponds to an integer by trying the conversion and catching the exception when it fails:

```
function Check_Integer_Value (Str : Unbounded_String) return Boolean is
   Dummy : Integer;
begin
   Dummy := Integer'Value (To_String (Str));
   return True;
exception
   when Constraint_Error =>
      return False;
end Check_Integer_Value;
```

With regard to `ReadValue`:

- Don’t initialize `Result` - it starts off as the empty string (and you really don’t want to start with the string `”NULL”`).
- It skips the first character input.
- What’s that `Skip_Line` for?

Try something like

```
function Read_Value return Unbounded_String is
   Value_Char : Character;
   Result : Unbounded_String;
begin
   loop
      Get_Immediate (Value_Char);
      exit when Value_Char = ';';
      if Is_Valid_Name_Input (Value_Char) then
         Result := Result & Value_Char;
      end if;
   end loop;
   return Result;
end Read_Value;
```